How to get FCM Token in Swift properly
I am trying to get FCM Token in my app using this code
        Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
        
        if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching FCM Token: \(error)");
        }
        else if let token = token {
            print("\(token)");
        }
    }

And I get my output as below. I don't know why it gives error first and there is FCM Token after few moments
Error fetching FCM Token: Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=505 "No APNS token specified before fetching FCM Token"
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=No APNS token specified before fetching FCM Token}
APNs token retrieved: 32 bytes
Firebase registration token: Optional("ckoUPFil4UEtrH2wDCrDVZ:APA91bG7fsR4WdxhN6mSwj_pjoKrX9fNW8TDSlIs7YCDCqqMgTjxHp03te4DMcPD4Y2Rrhg3sM9gjcP_QKndTECeVcEDYaQVsGcmxcKxRRQHDOw_IVZYPsoPho3iYJteE74GHsuuIjHg")


Did you assign UNUserNotificationCenter and FIRMessaging delegates?

@sonle Yes I did
